# TSR service procedure assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

A service procedure is given for ruling number 90H. After the initialize label, code snippets are written that record the procedure to the interrupt vector and end the program in TSR.

```
 jmp initialize

    msg db "this is 2 times", 0ah ,0dh, '$'
    
    isra90 proc
    
    push ax
    push dx
    lea dx, cs:msg
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h
    inc byte ptr msg+8
    
    exist:
    pop dx
    pop ax
    iret
    
    Endp
```

The procedure is triggered by a program in which, in the data segment, the string is defined:

msg db "hello $"

And in the code segment the command int 90H appears.

What the output will be? why it won't be "this is 2 times"? and otherwise it will print "hello"?

Answer (score 1):

### This interrupt service procedure for interrupt 90h can not print the message "this is 2 times".

When your second program runs the `int 90h` instruction and thus invokes the handler, **the message that is stored within the first program aka TSR program**, needs to be addressed through the `DS:DX` pointer. This is not the case because the `DS` segment register will be pointing to data that belongs to the second program.

Next could work. It temporarily sets `DS=CS` so as to get the correct far pointer in `DS:DX`. I can make this assumption because of the instruction `lea  dx, cs:msg` that implies that the message is within the code segment:

```
isra90 proc

 push ax
 push dx
 PUSH DS
 PUSH CS
 POP  DS
 lea  dx, cs:msg
 mov  ah, 09h
 int  21h
 inc  byte ptr msg+8

exit:
 POP  DS
 pop  dx
 pop  ax
 iret

Endp
```

### This interrupt service procedure for interrupt 90h can not print the message "hello ".

When your second program runs the `int 90h` instruction and thus invokes the handler, **the message that is stored within the second program**, needs to be addressed through the `DS:DX` pointer. This is not the case because, although the `DS` segment register will probably be pointing to the section that contains the "hello " string, the value of the *msg* label in the first program will almost certainly differ from the value of the *msg* label in the second program.